# General solution to diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was hoping someone could explain the general solution to the Cauchy problem for the diffusion equation.

So if the fundamental solution is, $G(x,t) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{4Dt}} dx$
,and the initial condition is, $u(x,0) = \phi(x)$, why is the general solution to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$
$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi (y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^{2}}{4Dt}} dy$

Comment: For starters, take another look at your $G(x,t)$.  $G(x,t)$ is obviously a function of $x$, but the RHS of your equation is an integral over all $x$ and therefore, has no $x$ dependence.  The integral does not belong there.

Comment: bob.sacramento, you are completely correct, thank you for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: No problem.  As for the rest of your question, the (correct) integral in your last equation is simply summing up all the contributions of $G$ from all of the locations on $y$, weighted by $\phi(y)$.

Comment: Can one think of the general solution as the convolution between $G(x,t)$ and $\phi (x)$? If so, why?

Comment: I'm going to try to make this a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the diffusion equation is linear.  This means that the total solution for a given set of sources is the sum of what the solution would be for each individual source in isolation.  You can think of $\phi(y,t_0)$ as a continuum set of sources at time $t_0$.  If only one little piece of $\phi$ was available, a delta-function, say, it would spread out as $G(x,t)$.  If several delta functions were available, they would all spread out like $G(x,t)$ and their combined effect would simply be the sum of them all.  Move from that situation to the situation where $\phi$ is completely present as the continuum function that you actually have, and the solution is the "sum" over all of $\phi$, or, more accurately, the integral you show.